# Intermixing of range and float alternatives in this code

Tags: python, range

Here's the problem:
A business applies discounts based on the number of units bought and the unit price. Write an application that asks the user for the number of units and unit price and calculates and prints the total price, the discount applied and the total discounted price. Display a suitable error message if the numbers of units is zero or less or if the price per unit is €0 or less.

Here's my code:

```
units_brought = float(input("Enter the number of units brought "))
unit_price = float(input("Enter the unit price "))

total_price = units_brought * unit_price

discount_applied = float(0)

total_discounted_price = total_price - discount_applied

if units_brought in range(1, 49) and unit_price in range(0.01, 10) :
    print("The total price is ",total_price,"\nThe discount applied is",discount_applied,"\nThe total discounted price is ",total_discounted_price)

    if unit_price in range(10.01, 100) :
        discount_applied = total_price * 0.05
        print("The total price is ", total_price, "\nThe discount applied is", discount_applied,"\nThe total discounted price is ", total_discounted_price)

    elif unit_price >= 100.1:
            discount_applied= total_price * 0.08
            print("The total price is ", total_price, "\nThe discount applied is", discount_applied,"\nThe total discounted price is ", total_discounted_price)

elif units_brought in range(50, 99) and unit_price in range(0.01, 10) :
    discount_applied = total_price * 0.12
    print("The total price is ", total_price, "\nThe discount applied is", discount_applied,
          "\nThe total discounted price is ", total_discounted_price)

    if unit_price in range(10.01, 100) :
        discount_applied = total_price * 0.18
        print("The total price is ", total_price, "\nThe discount applied is", discount_applied,
              "\nThe total discounted price is ", total_discounted_price)

    elif unit_price >= 100.01:
            discount_applied = total_price * 0.22
            print("The total price is ", total_price, "\nThe discount applied is", discount_applied,
                  "\nThe total discounted price is ", total_discounted_price)

elif units_brought >= 100 and unit_price in range(0.01, 10) :
    discount_applied = total_price * 0.21
    print("The total price is ", total_price, "\nThe discount applied is", discount_applied,
          "\nThe total discounted price is ", total_discounted_price)

    if unit_price in range(10.01, 100):
        discount_applied = total_price * 0.32
        print("The total price is ", total_price, "\nThe discount applied is", discount_applied,
              "\nThe total discounted price is ", total_discounted_price)

    elif unit_price >= 100.01:
        discount_applied = total_price * 0.43
        print("The total price is ", total_price, "\nThe discount applied is", discount_applied,
              "\nThe total discounted price is ", total_discounted_price)

elif units_brought <= 0:
    print("The number of units brought can't be zero or less")

elif unit_price <= 0:
    print("The unit price can't be zero or less")
```

This is what happens when it runs:

```
Enter the number of units brought 5
Enter the unit price 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Documents/My code/business_price_&_discounts.py", line 19, in <module>
    if units_brought in range(1, 49) and unit_price in range(0.01, 10) :
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So the problem seems to be the range functions in the if statements which can't have floats while at the same time my values requiring decimals, my question is, Is there an alternative to the range function here ?

Answer (score 2):

Your comparisons in the form

```
if unit_price in range(10.01, 100):
```

do not work, because `range` only takes integer arguments. Instead, you can use comparison chaining to write

```
if 10.01 <= unit_price < 100:
```

Also note that the `to` parameter in a range is *exclusive*, thus I used `< 100` in that comparison. However, in your case you probably want to check `<= 100`, given that in the following `elif` you test `>= 100.1`. Also note that due to floating point math it is possible that a value lies between `100.0` and `100.1`, even if you only use increments of `0.1`, thus you might want to test `<= 100` in the `if` and `> 100` in the following `elif`.